# Define a List of Objects in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# console app. My app has a class called Item. Item is defined like this:

```
public class Item {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I want to build a `List<Item> items`; In my head, C# had a shorthand way of defining a list at runtime. Something like:

```
List<Item> items = new List()
  .Add(new Item({ Id=1, Name="Ball", Description="Hello" })
  .Add(new Item({ Id=2, Name="Hat", Description="Test" });
```

Now I can't seem to find a short-hand syntax like I'm mentioning. Am I dreaming? Or is there a short-hand way to build a list of collections?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It has. The syntax would be like this:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item{ Id=1, Name="Ball", Description="Hello" },
    new Item{ Id=2, Name="Hat", Description="Test" }
}
```

Answer (score 33):

You can use an [`object & collection initializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)(C# 3.0 and above) like this:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>
{
   new Item { Id=1, Name="Ball", Description="Hello" },
   new Item { Id=2, Name="Hat", Description="Test" }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do just like this:

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
   new Item { Id=1, Name="Ball", Description="Hello" },
   new Item { Id=2, Name="Hat", Description="Test" }
};
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) are the details.

Answer (score 2):

in my opinion, Amir popovich answer is correct and this is the way that should be...

but in case we want to declare the list same as you mentioned in the question:

```
List<Item> items = new List()
  .Add(new Item({ Id=1, Name="Ball", Description="Hello" })
  .Add(new Item({ Id=2, Name="Hat", Description="Test" });
```

you can write an extension method that will allow you to achieve what you want

check this code ( small console application)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
            .AddAlso(new Item{ Id=1, Name="Ball", Description="Hello" })
            .AddAlso(new Item{ Id=2, Name="Hat", Description="Test" });

        foreach(var item in items)
            Console.WriteLine("Id {0} Name {1}, Description {2}",item.Id,item.Name,item.Description);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<T> AddAlso<T>(this List<T> list,T item)
    {
        list.Add(item);
        return list;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
}
```

and here a working [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4FB2pG)