# Create a List of string in Asp.Net Core

Tags: node.js, arrays, asp.net-core

this is a nodeJs code for creating an array Of teacher in a Course Model

```
  teacher: {
    fullName: String,
    email: String,
    _id: ObjectId,
    profile: String,
},
```

I want to Create this in Asp,.Net Core

how Should I Do it ?

I can create a StringArray like this

```
public string[] Teacher {get; set;}
```

But I dont know how to set that details into it

Comment: You need to create Teacher class with the properties.

Comment: That Node code isn't an array, it's just an object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define a List of Objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448455/define-a-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You're showing us your model in TypeScript. First you've to convert that model to a .net class. Which would result into something like:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Profile { get; set; }
}
```

Next you've to create a list or array of this model, since you said you had an array in JavaScript I will use it as well. So you will get:

```
Teacher[] teachers = new Teacher[5];
```

Next you want to set a value in this array (there are multiple ways how you can do this), one way of doing this is:

```
teachers[0] = new Teacher
{
    Id = "1",
    FullName = "Full Name",
    Email = "email@email.com",
    Profile = "Some profile information"
};
```